# Login as button and on right

Tags: razor, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to change the Login Partial that comes by default with an MVC Asp app to a button and moved to the right of my navigation bar (I am using twitter bootstrap). I would essentially like my button to look like one of the examples (not there any more it seems with v2.1 of bootstap) that are shown on the site with a person silohette and as a button on the right. I am not sure if anyone knows what I am talking about?

My HTMLPartial is as follows:

```
    @If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
        @<text>Welcome <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>!
        @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account")</text>
    Else
        @:@Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account")
    End If
```

And the portion of my view that this relates to is:

```
<!-- Menu for Reporting -->
<li class="pull-right">@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")</li>
```

As you can see I have tried to implement the pull-right in class but it has no effect. I have also in my partial changed:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account")
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account", New With {.class = "btn"})
```

But this yields a very over sized button with a strange behaviour and the name when logged in etc is not in the button (rather it shows above it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you shouldn't use pull-right with li tag. 
This should be done with div. you must put your code in to the following html and then youll be fine!

```
<div class="btn-group pull-right">
<a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">$Account</a><span class="caret"></span>
<ul class="dropdown-menu"><li>whatever you like</li><li>whatever you like</li></ul>
</div>
```

hope this will help :)